# Junit 5 with CamelTestSupport

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I'm trying to write unit test with JUnit 5 and Camel support.

1. JUnit 5 (5.0.0) Using following annotation @ method level in Class A:

```java
@Test
@ParameterizedTest(name = "Test case [{index}] name={3}")
@MethodSource("data")
@IfEnvProfile(profiles = {"preprod"}) (Customized Annotation)
```

2. Class A extends CamelTestSupport which is using Junit 4.Trying to hit service with below code:

```java
protected ResponseDto  getReponse(String testFile) throws Exception {
    Transaction tx= new Transaction ();
    final Map<String,Object> headers= setAllHeader(tx);
    // enter code here
    ResponseDto response =
        (RatingResponseDto) template.sendBodyAndHeaders("{{.location.enricher.uri}}",
            ExchangePattern.InOut, tx, headers);
}
```

where `location.enricher.uri` - http://localhost/rating-service/api/v1/rate/d155446421121/location/ (is up and running).

but when I run it, I'm always receiving `Nullpointer` exception on response.

Doubts:

1. Is it possible to combine JUnit 5 in class A and JUnit 4 in `CamelSupport` which extends Class A?
2. Do we have `CamelTestSupportClass` for JUnit 5?

Could anyone help?

Thanks,
Rajesh S

Answer (score 6):

Currently Camel supports Junit 5. You just have to include this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-test-junit5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And import the class:

```
import org.apache.camel.test.junit5.CamelTestSupport;
```

See [here](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/test-junit5.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

1. No: The class `org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport` only works with JUnit 4.
2. No: Camel does not yet have support for JUnit Jupiter (i.e., JUnit 5), but they have an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11807) to add such support in a later release.

Comment: Thanks  for your reply Sam.